# Trying to select rows that matched in vlookup excel

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am trying to select the rows of the results from my VLOOKUP and put the results in a neat table in another sheet. The row in my "M" column has a lot of NA and random numbers that were matched.

See this image for clarification:
[image]

I want to select all the rows that returned a result and move those rows to another sheet in a table without blank rows between the results. I am not sure how to do this but I know a resident stackoverflow pro probably thinks this is cake. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: You can upload the image to any image sharing website and post the link here - somebody with reputation will embed it in the post...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of a filter:

1. Select your table and put a filter (under Home tab, Sort & Filter).
2. Uncheck the `#N/A` in the selection filter (click the little grey box with black arrow for the column where there are the `#N/A` that appeared when you inserted the filters).
3. Copy and paste everything you need into the other sheet.

Comment: I knew someone had an easy answer, couldn't of been easier thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with some formulas:

- In the column next to your VLOOKUP (I assume it's column C) place a 'counter formula'- in D2, place `=IF(ISERROR(C2),0,1)`, in D3 and below: `=IF(ISERROR(C3),D2,D2+1)`
- Create a new table (say in starting in column F in the same sheet)
- In the first column of the table, just place increasing numbers (e.g. in F2: `=ROW()-1`)
- In the next columns, use INDEX/MATCH to retrieve the results, e.g. in G2: `=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(F2,D:D,0))`

Done!

Comment: I am sure this works too, but Jerry's filter solution was just too easy

Comment: No worries! Big advantage of this solution is that it updates automatically, though... ;-)